# How to select a class with this

Tags: jquery, this

I have a list of values, I want a script that when I hover a value, it show the values with the same class. I'm using an css opacity value to show these elements

so this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("text").hover(function() {
        $("text").css("opacity","0.2");
        $(this).  *this element's class*   .css("opacity","1");
    }, function() {
        $("text").css("opacity","1");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `text` only has one class, then you can query that by doing

```
$(this).attr("class");
```

You can then use that in the selector like this:

```
$("."+myclass).css("opacity","1");
```

See full example code: http://jsfiddle.net/zhwrf54e/

Answer (score 0):

Use getAttribute to get class and then append "." to use class selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("text").hover(function() {
    $("text").css("opacity","0.2");
    var className = $(this.getAttribute("class"));
    $("." + className ).css("opacity","1");
}, function() {
    $("text").css("opacity","1");
});
});
```

In case , you have multiple class , then need to split it with space and append "." with each one using loop.